# Why is Picture Box not Updating?

Tags: vb.net

I have a listbox, and when the selected index changes, it parses the text from that index to get a key, for a dictionary, it then uses this key to display the relevant images for that index. At least it is supposed to.

The `updatePics` subroutine works when I first add a new item to the listbox but not when I call it whilst changing index.

The `parseLstBoxItem` function works, I have used messageboxes to verify this.

The relevant keys and lists are present in the `jobsDict` dictionary, verified using autos.

I have even tried stepping through using a breakpoint but I can't work out what's going wrong. So any help at all would be hugely appreciated!

The relevant subs/functions are below:

Updates everything when the selected inbox is changed:

```
    Private Sub lstbxJobs_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstbxJobs.SelectedIndexChanged
    currentJob = parseLstBxItem(lstbxJobs.SelectedIndex)
    MsgBox(parseLstBxItem(lstbxJobs.SelectedIndex))
    updatePics()
    updateTicks(JobsDict(currentJob).stage)
    populateList()
End Sub
```

Updates the picture box and the numeric ticker below:

```
Public Sub updatePics()
    udImage.Maximum = JobsDict(currentJob).images.Count
    udImage.Minimum = 1
    udImage.Value = 1
    pctJobPics.ImageLocation = JobsDict(currentJob).images(0)
End Sub
```

The dictionary is defined as:

```
 Property JobsDict As New Dictionary(Of String, job)
```

It is populated in this subroutine (from a different form):

```
 Public Sub initJob(ID As String, notes As String, product As String, eta As Integer)
    Orders.JobsDict.Add(ID, New job)
    Orders.JobsDict(ID).ID = ID
    Orders.JobsDict(ID).notes = notes
    Orders.JobsDict(ID).product = product
    Orders.JobsDict(ID).stage = 0
    Orders.JobsDict(ID).images = imgList
    Orders.JobsDict(ID).ETA = eta
    Orders.JobsDict(ID).bumped = False
    Orders.chkItemStage.SetItemChecked(0, True)

End Sub
```

And `job` is a custom class defined as:

```
Public Class job
Property ID As String
Property product As String
Property ETA As Integer
Property stage As Integer
Property notes As String
Property images As New List(Of String)
Property bumped As Boolean

Public Sub nextStage()
    If stage < 4 Then
        stage += 1
        Orders.updateTicks(stage)
    Else
        MsgBox("Job is already finished")
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

The `imgList` is populated through a dragdrop as such:

```
 Public Sub pctadd_drop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles pctAdd.DragDrop
    Dim picStr() As String = CType(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop), String())
    Dim newList As List(Of String) = picStr.ToList
    For Each img In newList
        If Not imgList.Contains(img) Then
            imgList.Add(img)
        Else
            MsgBox("Image already present")
        End If
    Next
    pctAdd.ImageLocation = imgList(newList.Count - 1)
    udPics.Maximum = newList.Count
    udPics.Value = newList.Count
    udPics.Minimum = 1
    txtID.Text = Strings.Right(imgList(0).Remove(imgList(0).Length - 4, 4), 4)
End Sub
```

If there's anything I have omitted please let me know and I have attempted to debug this myself but I really can't see where the problem lies!

Comment: How is the `Dictionary` defined? How/where do you populate it?

Comment: I've added the extra details into the OP

Comment: Please show us how imgList gets populated.

Comment: I've noticed, the ticker values aren't getting updated correctly either

Comment: Exceptions in drag+drop event handlers are swallowed without a diagnostic.  Look in the Output window for a "First chance exception" notification.  Debug it by getting the debugger to stop when the exception is thrown  Debug > Exceptions dialog.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks, but NoAlias has solved the problem, it was in the jobinit, not the dragdrop. Thanks for the advice anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're assigning imgList to the Job's images Property in initJob is wrong.  The same imgList will be used for all jobs.

Change it to this:

```
Public Sub initJob(ID As String, notes As String, product As String, eta As Integer)

    Orders.JobsDict.Add(ID, New job)
    Orders.JobsDict(ID).ID = ID
    Orders.JobsDict(ID).notes = notes
    Orders.JobsDict(ID).product = product
    Orders.JobsDict(ID).stage = 0
    Orders.JobsDict(ID).images = New List(of String)

    For Each strImage in imgList

        Orders.JobsDict(ID).images.Add(strImage)

    Next

    Orders.JobsDict(ID).ETA = eta
    Orders.JobsDict(ID).bumped = False
    Orders.chkItemStage.SetItemChecked(0, True)

End Sub
```

Edit:

To clarify more, when you were assigning the images Property to the List that was passed in, you're actually assigning it to imgList.  Ultimately you had a number of jobs that all shared that same variable.  By assigning the images Property to its own unique instance of a List(of String) and copying the values from imgList, images is unique for each Job (assuming that the values for imgList changed).

Comment: Thank you so much @NoAlias - would you mind explaining what I did wrong in a tad more detail so that I don't make this mistake again please

Comment: I have added more clarification to the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

The lovely method `PictubeBox.Update` will help you.

```
Public Sub updatePics()
     udImage.Maximum = JobsDict(currentJob).images.Count
     udImage.Minimum = 1
     udImage.Value = 1
     pctJobPics.ImageLocation = JobsDict(currentJob).images(0)
     pctJobPics.Image = JobsDict(currentJob).images(0) 'if don't works, disable this
     Call pctJobPics.Update()
End Sub
```

Comment: Doesn't happen nothing?

Comment: literally nothing... My original code works fine in every other circumstance except this one

Comment: The Job class as posted has the images property as a List(Of String), so you can't set the Image property of the PictureBox to a string.

Comment: @LarsTech I'm setting the imagelocation property to string rather than the image property... the problem has been solved by NoAlias though

Comment: @JamesHughes I know, but I don't think Gabriel caught that based on his answer.

Comment: @LarsTech ahh okay, that would make sense, sorry